# v-for syntax in a Vue.js component template

Tags: vue.js

What is "props.item" in the following code in a Vue.js component template?

```
  <div class="expand" v-if="expand">
    <v-progress-linear :indeterminate="true"
                       height="5"
                       v-if="testTable.length === 0" />
    <v-data-table v-else-if="tableHeaders"
                  :headers="tableHeaders"
                  :items="testTable"
                  hide-actions>
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td v-for="(field, key) in props.item" :key="key">{{ field }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

There is no definition of "item" above this code snippet. The props of the component are defined as follows:

```
props: {
  testData: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
},
```

so I cannot figure out where to search for 'item' and where does it come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` is a piece of data that is passed to the slot `items` in the `v-data-table` component so that it will be accessible in the parent component when `v-data-table` component is used; i.e. in `v-data-table` there is a slot defined as:

```js
<slot name="items" :item="..."></slot>
//                  ^^^^  and this is where the item comes from
```

You can read more about [scoped slots here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

Comment: Is "props" used with slot-scope="props"  something like a namespace? Can I give it another name like "props1"?

Comment: From my understanding, yes, you should be able to use whatever name you want. You can even destructure it with `slot-scope="{ item }"` so that you don't have to give it a name.